# React Native Android Brotli support

Tags: android, react-native, brotli

I would like to use brotli for network requests (fetch) in my React Native App, but it works only for iOS (not Android). I'v upgraded RN to the latest version 0.68.1, tested different REST APIs with brotli support and used a fresh RN project with no success. It just can't decode, even if I use the 'Accept-Encoding' : 'br' header.

I would appreciate any additional informations like: how to enable brotli with fetch in React Native, why isn't it supported in Android although Google created it?